# Click button to amend textfield, textFieldDidEndEditing not called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i've got a couple of checks going on within textFieldDidEndEditing which basically enable or disable the input of a text box, they seem to be working fine.

When I have an IBAction associated with a button that affects the values inside of a text box, does textFieldDidEndEditing not get called? It seems to only respond when i'm actually within a textBox typing.

I have this method which resets my text boxes and I want to run textFieldDidEndEditing after it but don't know how to pass a generic textField to it as the sender of the reset method isnt a text field.

```
- (IBAction)reset;
{
    txtCost.text = @"";
    txtPrice.text = @"";
    txtProfit.text = @"";
    txtMargin.text = @"";
    txtMarkup.text = @"";
    txtTaxPercentage.text = @"";
    txtTaxAmount.text = @"";



}
```

Thanks, any clarification or help would be great.

Comment: create IBOutlets  for each and every UITextFields and also delegate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate method `textFieldDidEndEditing` will not be called if you are manually changing the text inside of a textField using another sender. That delegate method responds to `resignFirstResponder` so it will never be fired in your case.

What you can do is manually call it though based on the textField you want.

```
[self textFieldDidEndEditing:_yourTextField];
```